# USB Zero gadget on Android Kernel

Tags: android, kernel, usb, zero

Is there anyone who can use USB Zero gadget in android kernel?
I have some problem with USB Zero gadget.

To load usb zero gadget on android, 
I think It must use 'modprobe' command 
but Android don't support modprobe command.

I also use busybox but also android can't not support /proc/modules/
.

Please give me any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modprobe is supported on some Android devices, but you must be root to use it. If you don't have /proc/modules, theres no support for modules for your kernel.

Even if you did have support for modules, you'd still need usb zero compiled against the specific kernel you're running which I guess you haven't done.

So, to solve your problem you should:

1. Enable support for dynamic loadable modules - this means you need to compile a new kernel for your device and enable the loadable module option in .config
2. Compile usb zero for your kernel - this means you need to compile the kernel module yourself against the kernel tree from step 1
3. Enable root access to be privileged enough to load modules - this means you either root your device or enable root access by modifying the kernel code

Anyhow, theres no ready made solution for these things

Comment: It is very useful information for me.
Thank you for comment.